# Every closed surface divides a closed 3-manifold $X$ into two parts if and only if $H_1(X)$ is finite

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

My friend is looking for proof of the following statement

> Every closed surface divides a closed 3-manifold $X$ into two parts if and only if $H_1(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is finite.

Rumor source: [Justin Roberts - Knot Knotes](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ejustin/Roberts-Knotes-Jan2015.pdf), page 104

Comment: False without adjectives, consider $\Bbb{RP}^2 \subset \Bbb{RP}^3$. True for *oriented* closed surfaces. Proof: If $\Sigma \subset X$ doesn't divide $X$ into two pieces, then 'oriented intersection number with $\Sigma$' defines a non-trivial homomorphism $\pi_1(X) \to \Bbb Z$, hence a non-trivial element of $\text{Hom}(H_1(X);\Bbb Z)$. Conversely, given such a non-trivial homomorphism, realize it by a smooth map $f: X \to S^1$ and let $\Sigma$ be $f^{-1}(r)$ for some regular value $r$; this is a closed oriented subsurface which does not divide $X$ into two pieces.

Comment: Nothing here is special to dimension 3. If I remember, this story (or at least hints at it) appear in Guillemin and Pollack's book on differential topology.

Comment: Thank you! I'll think about this proof. Yes, the book claims that this is true for all manifolds (dimension is not mentioned).

Comment: @mme  I remember a similar phrase in Hirsch diff topology : ebery  codimension one compact summanfiold of a compact manifold separate the space provided all thing are orientable

Comment: A further comment on @mme's example. $\mathbb{RP}^2 \subset \mathbb{RP}^3$, is the first example of a one-sided Heegaard Splitting (see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-76/issue-1/One-sided-Heegaard-splittings-of-3-manifolds/pjm/1102807036.pdf for further background). So you can actually use this trick as a way of decomposing 3-manifolds. If you assume that ($X$ is orientable and) $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is finite and odd (aka $X$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ homology sphere), you can show there are no one-sided non-orientable surfaces embedded in $X$.